Difference between Stochastic Volatility (SV) model and Stochastic-Local Volatility (SLV) Model
I cannot get what's the difference between SV and SLV models.
The SLV model contains a stochastic volatility component represented by a volatility process and a local volatility component.
Based on this definition, why SABR model is not classified as SLV model but SV model?
When alpha is set to 0, isn't the remaining part a local volatility component?

Alpha controls the height of IV in sabr, see https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63750/54838. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70964/54838 explains LV and SLV. SV has no local vol component at all. SABR is just Blacks Scholes in VOL space.

@AKdemy what exactly is local vol component? Isn't F^beta local vol component? thanks
